# Looking for specific version of SQL*Plus with GUI

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am looking for SQL*Plus release 9 to release 11, which it is with a GUI, like the picture shown below. 
[SQL PLUS with GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh4cC.jpg)

I couldn't find any installer from Oracle OTN as it has been replaced by version 11 and version 12.
I have tried to use SQL*PLus release 12, it is not as handy as the one with GUI.

If any of you have a copy of it and dont mind sharing it with me or you have an idea where can i get it from, it would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

GUI SQL*Plus (sqlplusw.exe) was available up to 10g version. However, it is no longer available for download, as stated on [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html):

> Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download.
>   The software is available as a media or FTP request for those
>   customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any
>   edition.

Though, if you have a valid license, you might get it - just contact Oracle.

Alternatively, consider downloading & installing Oracle [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), a modern free GUI tool.

Comment: I understand that there is a new sqlplus version but it is having some showing me some weird error which doesnt happen on the GUI SQL*PLUS. And have no idea how to use sql developer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing much I can do for you.